# JSON Request for an Image into UIImageView

Tags: json, swift, request

I would like to download a picture of a json file online.
This image should be displayed in a UIImageView.

I have no idea how this works because I am new to Swift.

At least I know that I need a JSON request but as I can bring the image in the ImageView I do not know

I've tried to download the image with a JSON request, but I have not managed it yet

```
public func fetchJSONPicture() {
        let urlString = "EXAMPLE-URL"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else { return }

                do {

                    self.coursesPicture = [try JSONDecoder().decode(CoursePicture.self, from: data)]
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Failed to decode:", jsonErr)
                }
            }
            }.resume()


    }
```

There may be a very simple solution to the problem, but I have not found it yet.
Could someone help me with that?

Comment: Add the definition of `CoursePicture`.

Comment: Also, is the image url contained in the JSON?

Comment: Yes it is 
This is what it looks like in the JSON: 

{
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "EXAMPLE_URL"
    },
     "_links": {
        
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After parsing the `JSON`, when you have the `"EXAMPLE_URL"`, you can fetch the `image` from a `URL` using `URLSession`, i.e.

```
if let url = URL(string: "EXAMPLE_URL") {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        if let data = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens. Xcode also gives me no error in the console. I have done it exactly in the JSON request. I also did it under the JSON request.